# Show / Hide Modifiers Based on Selection

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to show / hide modifiers based on a selection.  For instance I am building a store who rents licenses for a period of time (3, 6, and 12 month).  I want to show a different set of options based on one of the selections above.   Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is anything out of the box that can do that.
I'd likely rework the logic and create 3 separate products with modifiers required and either via JavaScript or URL segments load required 'product'.

You could load all 3 on one page and via JavaScript hide them and use a simple radio group to trigger a show/hide function or load via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

EE won't do that out of the box (that I know of). You're looking for a 'chained select' option, I think - where the first select determines the options available of the second select.

Depending on what your needs are, try one of these jquery:

- Chained Select: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained
- Chosen: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible out of the box with Store. As long as your chained select options don't require price modifiers, you could do this using a jQuery chained select plugin as mentioned above, combined with "custom text modifiers", which allow you to submit arbitrary text fields along with the order:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#inputcustom_modifier_name

You could also simply add all the possible modifier options in the publish page, and then use one of the jQuery select plugins to only display the correct modifiers to uses on the front end. How complicated this will be depends on how many products you have like this which need to be set up.